# how to type code in a insert line as the video shows

Tags: terminal

I'm setting up a SSH tunneling followed by a instruction video
[instruction video in HPC NYU website](https://wikis.nyu.edu/download/attachments/53859428/scp_ssh_tunnel_mac.mov?version=1&modificationDate=1390843933000&api=v2)

everything works fine until 01:10. the video shows type ":wq" at the very bottom line with replacing"---insert---", but I cannot type on the line. how did they do that? 
please help! 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like he's using vim to edit a file. If you type the colon while not in edit mode (hit esc if you're in edit mode), you'll see the colon appear at the bottom. Then you can type wq and hit enter to write (w) and quit (q).

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works! but after I type in ssh hpctunnel, it shows "/Users/chrislab/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: st
/Users/chrislab/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options". what should i do?

Comment: never mind! I was missing one configuration! Thank you!